# how to hidden image over image in css

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
         <header>
         <div id="header">
            <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/vdwnuxg4x/logo.png" alt="logo" /> 
            </div>   
            <div class="header-content">
               <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/tndmtfylt/banner.png" alt="banner" />
               <div class="issue">
                  <img  class="issue-image-1" src="http://s22.postimg.org/jniqdjncd/issue_no_img.png" alt="issue" />    
                <span class="issue-no">Issue No.<br /><b>376</b></span>
               </div>
               <div class="header-content-center">
                  <p>
                     <span class="new">NEW!</span>&nbsp;
                     <date>JUN O7,2013</date>
                  </p>
                  <p><i>Get your breakpoints on.</i></p>
                  <h1 class="h1-clear">DOT NET ARTICLES</h1>
                  <p><i>by</i>&nbsp;<a class="jon" href="#"> JOHN WOO</a><i>-10 comments</i></p>
                 <form>
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr-style" />
         </header>
```

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vas4bxu5/

here banner.png and issue_no_img.png are displayed in header, it shows, backside of issue image, there is display of banner image, i want to hidden that .

I used `z-index:9999;` or `z-index:-9999;` , still nothing change.

May i know what is the exact css property to fix this.

Comment: May i know the exact problem

Comment: do u want to hide your banner image i.e., `banner.png` is that your question

Comment: do you want to hide your `orange star bg`

Comment: no no, not like that. i want look like this, see this that two images deeply. http://s30.postimg.org/j6ss2tptt/layout.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change some styles and by the way `z-index` works with positioned elements, change your CSS like following:

```
.issue
{
    width: 23px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative; /* added this */
}
.issue-no
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: 30px; /* updated this */
    position: absolute; 
    top: -80px; /* updated this */
    line-height: normal;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vas4bxu5/1/)

Comment: Is the question is about centering the element

Comment: here won't use z-index property?

Comment: @888 `z-index` is not needed unless you want to move that banner behind! by default it will be on top of background image!

Comment: May i know, where is the exact situation to use z-index property?

Comment: @888 You can refer some modal popup to get the brief idea what z-index does!